# Simplify integral with random functions and their derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, mathematica, symbolic-computation

Let $F$ be a function and $f=F'$ the derivative of $F$. Then we obviously have for arbitrary $a,b$:
$$
\int_a^b f(x) F(x)^9 dx =\frac{F(b)^{10}-F(a)^{10}}{10}.
$$
Is there a way to obtain this result **in Mathematica**? I know that there is a way to do symbolic integration and taking derivatives but I'm now quite sure how I can define $f$ as *the derivative of* $F$. I am thus looking for how to define $f,F$ in Mathematica in such a way that if I call `Integrate[f[x]*F[x]^9,{x,a,b}]` it will return me  the result `(F[b]^10-F[a]^10)/10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking about. if you let $u = F(x)$ then $du = F'(x)dx = f(x)dx$ and the integral becomes
$$
\int f(x) F(x)^9dx = \int u^9du = \frac{u^{10}}{10}+C=\frac{F(x)^{10}}{10}+C.
$$

**UPDATE**

In Mathematica, use

`Integrate[F'[x]*F[x]^9, x]` or `Integrate[F'[x]*F[x]^9, {x,a,b}]`

In a similar query, here is the [result from WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%20F%27%5Bx%5D*F%5Bx%5D%5E9,x%5D)

Comment: Sorry, I added a very important part: in Mathematica I would like to do this in mathematica!

Comment: I can see why you were surprised by my question :)

Comment: @Darkwizie see update

Comment: Thank you! It is remarkably simpler than I imagined, love the simplicity of Mathematica!

Comment: This does work for indefinite integrals but when I make them definite it no longer works? (Integrate[ F'[x]*F[x]^9,{x,1,2}])
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B+F%27%5Bx%5D*F%5Bx%5D%5E9,%7Bx,1,2%7D%5D

Comment: @Darkwizie i have a feeling it will work in Mathematica even though it does not work in WolframAlpha